# Setting up every sentence (or string) in a text have its own URL

Tags: python, django

So I want to have a webpage that has a text - say a short story.

I want every sentence in the short story to have its own URL and page.

The idea would be to allow users to save and comment on each sentence.

It would be similar to what RapGenius does for lyrics. I.e. a song has its own page (https://genius.com/Eminem-venom-music-from-the-motion-picture-lyrics). But each line in the song can also have its own URL/page (https://genius.com/15303513 or https://genius.com/15306806)

What is the best way to approach this?

1. Should I be splitting the short story into sentences beforehand,
   then import it into the database?
2. Or should I be looking to upload the short story as a whole text
   (either onto the database or on the server) and then try to split it
   after the fact?
3. Or is "splitting up" the story into sentences the wrong approach
   completely? Should I be looking to have the URL generate based off
   the sentence's location in the text?

I'm currently leaning towards option 1.

I would appreciate any help or guidance! Looking to build my first proper Django app (after doing a bunch of tutorials) and I would like to make sure I'm on the right path.

Comment: I guess more like option 1. Connect the song model with sentence model and In sentence model add all the info, and then show all the sentence of one song and add its link in template.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's particularly a "right" answer here.

If you are *always* going to split per sentence, I'd just Keep it Simple and go with (1) and store each sentence separately in the database.  It makes a simple one-to-one relationship between sentence and page, and decreases the amount of work your code has to do each time the story or sentence is viewed.  It also means if you modify a sentence nothing will get messed up.

OTOH, if you want to have some sort of user-definable "highlight" like genius.com, that won't work, as of course you won't know what the user wants to highlight until they're there.

The difference between (1) and (2) seems like more of an implementation decision - when you split the sentences out.  It really depends on how you're adding these stories to the database. In the long run you'll probably benefit from having an automated process on the server that does this, but that might not be the MVP (minimum viable product) solution for now.

(3) seems like a massive PITA and could get messed up if you edit the text anywhere above the split out area.